# ¿Google puede posicionar esta página si utilizo esto al principio de la misma?

Tags: php, seo, google-adsense

Una página que sólo interesa dar acceso a las personas que inician sesión, tiene al principio de todo este siguiente código para evitar que accedan los que no estén registrados. Mi duda es si teniendo esto, Google podrá restrear su contenido y posicionarlo, o poder utilizar Google Adsens por ejemplo en esta página, o diréctamente le es ilegible porque los robots "no se registran, entonces no lo ven".

S_SESSION['idUsuario'] en este caso, se crear sólo al iniciar sesión de usuario:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Un saludo y gracias.

Comment: En ese caso tendrías que usar `robots.txt` y decirle que sitios no quieres que Google siga. Algo asi: `User-Agent: Googlebot` `Disallow: /carpeta/`. En este caso solo Google no podrá seguir esta carpeta, si quieres que otros buscadores hagan lo mismo tienes que cambiar `Googlbot` por `*`.

Comment: Agradezco tu respuesta. El tema es que quiero poner publicidad Google Adsense en esta página. Adsense me dice que no es apta la web para Adsense. Y me temo que pueda ser porque en la cabecera tengo este código php que si el que intenta entrar no es usuario, diréctamente lo saca a la index.php. Entonces me temo que google no lo pueda indexar. No se si me excplico bien. Un saludo y gracias.

Comment: Tu te refieres a poner publicidad en el login del sitio?

Comment: no, perdona, el dónde colocarlo no es la cuestión. La cuestión es que Adsense dice "Esta web no es apta". Y mi deducción ha sido que quizás el motivo sea que tengo en 2 páginas ese código de php que si el usuario no está registrado, lo redirige automáticamente al index.php no pudiendo las arañas de google rastrearse o indexarlas (porque no le da tiempo a ver). "salvo que la araña se registre e inicie sesión". xD No se si me explico.

Comment: Aaaaah.... entiendo... creo que en todo caso tendrías que buscar porque Google te dice eso y leer los consejos que Google da para que los anuncios tengan mejor alcance. Quizás Google te esta diciendo que la web no es apta por de contenido, etc.. [Aqui](https://support.google.com/adsense/answer/6185995?hl=es) puedes saber y probar si el sitio es apto para incluir anuncios. En mi opinión, descarto que vaya a ser un problema con `PHP`.

Comment: Como tu bien dices... los robots "no se registran, entonces no lo ven" , las páginas que son solo para usuarios registrados son páginas privadas y google ni puede ni debe indexarlas (Incluirlas en su indice para que puedan mostrarse como resultado de una consulta)... Otra cosa diferente es Adsense, los anuncios si se pueden mostrar donde tu quieras siempre que cumplan con las políticas de adsense.